# Подскажите как сделать кнопку просмотра, ячейки?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

Вот пример фото.Подскажите как сделаться такую функцию.Если человек посещает страницу фиксируется просмотр?Как такой метод называется?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что не понятного? просмотр страницы сделать label

Answer (score 0):

Это надо делать не на клиенте (iOS, Android), а через сервер, иначе только на одном устройстве и будет виден счетчик просмотров.

Общая логика в наиболее простом варианте такая: при запросе страницы перед отдачей ее сервером обновляем базу данных и добавляем "+1 просмотр" в соответствующую колонку.

Если делать более сложные варианты (которые учитывают просмотры от конкретного пользователя и физическое попадание контента в область просмотра), то потребуется создавать дополнительную таблицу в БД (в которой будут отслеживаться просмотры пользователей) и инициировать отправку запросов непосредственно при попадании контента в физическую область просмотра (здесь лучше собирать такие запросы в группы на клиенте и время от времени отправлять пакеты данных для обновления счетчиков).